# PHP Multi Login Ranking

Tags: php, mysql

so I have my site which i am coding, in my login.php, this is the source:

```
<?php
    include "out_config.php";
    session_start();

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    if(!$username) {
        header("Location: ../index?errormsg=nousername");
    }
    if(!$password) {
        header("Location: ../index?errormsg=nopassword");
    }       

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

    if($rankcheck == "Administrator" || $rankcheck == "Client") {
        $check = 1;
    }
    else {
        $check = 0;
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if($count==1 && $check == 1) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                header("Location: ../home");
            }
            else {
                header("location: ../index?errormsg=invalidlogin");
            }
    }
?>
```

1st: I know MySQL is depreciated but I want to use MySQL because my Host Supports MySQL more than MySQLi/PDO.

2nd: You can see my $rankcheck won't work. My rank check lines are included in out_config.php, the source for it is:

```
<?php 
<Removed Details>
$connect = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
$selectdb = mysql_select_db($db);

$IP = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT `rank` FROM `users` where username='$user'");
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$rankcheck = mysql_result($sql2,0);
}
?>
```

So you can see, it looks all fine. :P

Now, the problem is that I am trying to allow access to this area only to people who are ranked 'Administrator' and 'Client' so it won't work. My Database structure is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAzr9.png

It does not grant access to User and Awaiting usergroup members. But it does not even let Administrator's and Clients. ( I am sure there is no Password Encryption yet ).

If you could help me, it would be really helpful!

Comment: how you are getting $user in `out_config.php`

Comment: plaintext passwords make me sad :-(

Comment: @NicholasKing is right, use a [strong password hashing algorithm](http://php.net/password) when storing passwords.

Comment: The $user is defined in login.php

Answer (score 0):

in the moment you are including your "out_config.php" $username and $password is not set

change to this:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    include "out_config.php";

    if(!$username) {
        header("Location: ../index?errormsg=nousername");
    }
    if(!$password) {
        header("Location: ../index?errormsg=nopassword");
    }       

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

    if($rankcheck == "Administrator" || $rankcheck == "Client") {
        $check = 1;
    }
    else {
        $check = 0;
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if($count==1 && $check == 1) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                header("Location: ../home");
            }
            else {
                header("location: ../index?errormsg=invalidlogin");
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: It is via the form action="inc/login"> ? so as soon as the user submits the data it logs in?

Comment: in your example you first include "out_config.php" and after that you fill the variables $username and $password from the GET array. you should first set variables an then include - see my answer

Comment: btw: you really should improve your code - its absolutely unsafe(sql injection...)

Comment: I know it's SQL Injectable, that's why I am just trying to learn SQL. + After clearing with mysql_real_escape_string it becomes safe in MySQL. I am learning MySQLi Prepared statements as PDO is out of my brains.

Comment: The answer you provided did not work, I did switch them, and it still is the same..... :[ Plus would you help me transfer all my code to MySQLi Prepared statements?